# Unir resultados de uma sql em apenas uma linha

Tags: mysql

Tenho o seguinte banco de dados:

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `materiais`; 
USE `materiais`;
 --
-- Table structure for table `categoria`
--

 CREATE TABLE `categoria` (
  `id_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `descricao_categoria` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sin_ativo` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_categoria`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `categoria`
--

 INSERT INTO `categoria` VALUES (1,'travessas','S'),(2,'Capa Cromada','S'),(3,'Coifas Vedante','S'),(4,'Chassis Metálicos','S'),(5,'Quadros Hidráulicos','S'),(6,'Tampa de Inspeção','S'),(7,'Abraçadeira Sextavada Tipo M','S'),(8,'Ponto de Filtro','S'),(9,'TE Ducha higiênica','S'),(10,'Carenagens Plásticas','S');

--
-- Table structure for table `metricas`
--

 CREATE TABLE `metricas` (
  `id_metricas` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `descricao` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_metricas`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `metricas`
--

 INSERT INTO `metricas` VALUES (1,'A Máx (mm)'),(2,'A Min (mm)'),(3,'B'),(4,'C'),(5,'B (mm)');

--
-- Table structure for table `imagem`
--

 CREATE TABLE `imagem` (
  `id_imagem` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `caminho` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sin_ativo` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'S',
  `produto_id_produto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_imagem`),
  KEY `fk_imagem_produto1` (`produto_id_produto`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_imagem_produto1` FOREIGN KEY (`produto_id_produto`) REFERENCES `produto` (`id_produto`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `imagem`
--

 --
-- Table structure for table `especificacao`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `especificacao`;
 CREATE TABLE `especificacao` (
  `id_codigo` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `id_metricas` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `valor` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_codigo`,`id_metricas`),
  KEY `fk_codigo_has_metricas_metricas1` (`id_metricas`),
  KEY `fk_codigo_has_metricas_codigo1` (`id_codigo`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_codigo_has_metricas_codigo1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_codigo`) REFERENCES `codigo` (`id_codigo`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_codigo_has_metricas_metricas1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_metricas`) REFERENCES `metricas` (`id_metricas`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `especificacao`
--

 INSERT INTO `especificacao` VALUES ('CAN16',3,'57'),('CAN16',4,'63'),('CC00000016',1,'457'),('CC00000016',2,'317'),('CC00000016',5,'53'),('ESP400',1,'394'),('ESP400',2,'254');

--
-- Table structure for table `codigo`
--

 CREATE TABLE `codigo` (
  `id_codigo` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `id_produto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sin_ativo` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S',
  `descricao` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_codigo`),
  KEY `fk_codigo_produto1` (`id_produto`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_codigo_produto1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_produto`) REFERENCES `produto` (`id_produto`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
 --
-- Dumping data for table `codigo`
--

 INSERT INTO `codigo` VALUES ('CAN16',7,'S',NULL),('CC00000016',8,'S',NULL),('ESP400',7,'S',NULL),('TMMC390100',2,'S',NULL),('TMRP1239070',1,'S',NULL),('TMRP3439070',1,'S',NULL);

--
-- Table structure for table `produto`
--

 CREATE TABLE `produto` (
  `id_produto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `descricao` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `sin_ativo` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S',
  `id_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_produto`),
  KEY `fk_produtos_categoria` (`id_categoria`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_produtos_categoria` FOREIGN KEY (`id_categoria`) REFERENCES `categoria` (`id_categoria`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `produto`
--

 INSERT INTO `produto` VALUES (1,'Travessa para Registro de Pressão','S',1),(2,'Travessa para Monocomando','S',1),(3,'Travessa Tubular Para Cotovelo','S',1),(4,'Travessa para Distribuidor','S',1),(5,'Travessa para Aquecedor e tanque','S',1),(6,'Travessa para registro de gaveta','S',1),(7,'Conjunto Capa Cromada','S',2),(8,'CONJUNTO CAPA CROMADA CANOPLA EM LATÃO CROMADO','S',2),(9,'CONJUNTO CAPA CROMADA CANOPLA EM ABS','S',2),(10,'COIFA SIMPLES','S',3),(11,'COIFA SILICONE','S',3),(12,'COIFA TRIPLA','S',3),(13,'COIFA DUPLA','S',3),(14,'COIFA QUADRUPLA','S',3),(15,'CARENAGEM TANQUE','S',10),(16,'CHASSI TANQUE','S',4),(17,'QUADRO CHUVEIRO DE SOBREPOR - 2 TRAVESSAS','S',5),(18,'TAMPA DE INSPEÇÃO VENTILADA','S',6),(19,'ABRAÇADEIRA SEXTAVADA TIPO M','S',7),(20,'PONTO DE FILTRO','S',8),(21,'TE DUCHA HIGIÊNICA','S',9);
```

Ao realizar a sql:

```
select p.id_produto, p.descricao, c.id_codigo, m.descricao,e.valor
from produto as p inner join codigo as c ON p.id_produto =
c.id_produto inner join especificacao as e ON e.id_codigo =
c.id_codigo inner join metricas as m ON e.id_metricas  = m.id_metricas
where c.id_produto = 7
```

O resultado para cada produto é dado em duas linhas com no exemplo:

```
id_produto  descricao             id_codigo     descricao   valor
7          Conjunto Capa Cromada    CAN16           B       57
7          Conjunto Capa Cromada    CAN16           C       63
7          Conjunto Capa Cromada    ESP400      A Máx (mm)  394
7          Conjunto Capa Cromada    ESP400      A Min (mm)  254
```

Preciso que o valor retornado apareça separado por produto em apenas uma linhas, por exemplo:

`id_produto   descricao id_codigo   descricao valor descricao   valor`

```
7      Conjunto Capa Cromada CAN16       B    57    C              63
```

Como resolver?

Comment: Quais os critérios para passar do resultado com 4 linhas para 1 linha só? Pode agrupar os resultados com `GROUP BY` por exemplo ou então especificar melhor o seu `WHERE`. Esclareça melhor o que pretende ver no fim como resultado. (O seu código no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98c12b/3))

Comment: Gostaria que o resultado de id_codigo, ficasse em apenas uma linha. Algo como 7          Conjunto Capa Cromada    CAN16           B       57 C       63

Comment: olhei mas observe que o valor da linha de baixo o C       63 não apareceu.

Comment: Sugiro você achar outra solução para o problema, pois para cada opção possível de 'descricao' você teria 2 colunas a mais na sua consulta. Não funciona assim. De repente, você faz outra pergunta relatando o problema que você quer resolver e alguém responde a melhor forma.

Comment: Um problema é o que o número de colunas pode variar, talvez o uso de um CASE com MAX  resolva mas não creio em solução via sql , talvez o uso de um gerador de relatório que faça referência cruzada (Crystal Reports por exemplo) seja o melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então acho que para resolver seu problema você pode usar uma função de agregação como  [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) do mysql.

```
select 
    p.id_produto
  , p.descricao
  , c.id_codigo
  , group_concat(m.descricao order by p.id_produto, ', ') as descricao
  , group_concat(e.valor  order by p.id_produto, ', ') as valor
from produto as p 
inner join codigo as c ON p.id_produto = c.id_produto 
inner join especificacao as e ON e.id_codigo = c.id_codigo 
inner join metricas as m ON e.id_metricas  = m.id_metricas
where c.id_produto = 7
group by p.id_produto
  , p.descricao
  , c.id_codigo
;
```

obs: Não tenho certeza se a sintaxe está correta, achei essa informação [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9456416), usando como base o listagg do Oracle 11g.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, Obrigado.

Comment: Opa. Fico feliz por ter ajudado!